# Jquery UI Datepicker not working while everything looks fine

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

How to make this snippet working?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery("#date-from").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input class="from hasDatepicker" id="date-from" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line on top: `<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` and remove the class `hasDatepicker` from `input` tag so your `input` tag will be `<input class="from" id="date-from" type="text" />`

```js
$("#date-from").datepicker();
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input class="from" id="date-from" type="text" />
```